# Fit a JTable in a JPane and Scroll vertically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, panel, jscrollpane

I've got a panel such as this:

```
    panel2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    panel2.setSize(185,400);
    panel2.setLocation(5,150);
    panel2.add(table1,sp1);
```

and a in it there is a JTable :

```
    Object[][] data = {{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},
    {000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},
    {000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},
    {000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},
    {000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},{000,00},
    {000,00},{000,00},};

    String[] columnNames = {"DIN","DEN"};

    DefaultTableModel defTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
    JTable table1 = new JTable(defTableModel);

    JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(table1);

    Dimension scrollpaneDimension = new Dimension(185, 400);
    sp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(sp1.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(scrollpaneDimension);
    table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

I've pretty much tried everything I found, I've tested the GridBagLayout and using its constraints and `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` to give to the table the size of the panel. I tried to do it with MigLayout and the last try was with the code presented above. I have to get the table fit the panel and scrollable but something goes wrong. Also I have hard time getting the headers of the columns shown, but the main problems are the previous two. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add table1 twice. Just do this

```
panel2.add(sp1); // instead of - panel2.add(table1,sp1);
```

You've already add the `table1` to the scroll pane

```
JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
```

Comment: yes this gave kinda the solution now now half the scrollbar is being cut by the component and and from the left side the zeros cant be seen they re equally cut from the component.Is there any way possible to save this time or i just have to grow my panel?

Comment: i just resized the panel the easy solution so dont bother and thank you :)